# WHY do we use AQAB (2^16+1) as public exponent in RSA?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

So I have been learning RSA and really trying to understand it from a math perspective. I think I have a pretty good handle on it now except for one thing.

In all the explanations and tutorials I have studied, when it comes time to making a public exponent, it’s usually randomly generated as a coprime of (p-1)(q-1). Usually this is a small number because it’s easier to learn that way.

However, in the real world I understand it’s pretty common practice to use AQAB as the public exponent. Upon googling this I find plenty of people telling me WHAT AQAB is, but I’m not finding sufficient answers as to WHY it is used.

My assumption is that randomizing the public exponent is not very important - as opposed to randomizing p and q. And I know I read that 65537 is kind of a sweet spot between security and speed. But with that said I’m still having trouble grasping the WHY.

Comment: The smaller the exponent, the faster the encryption process. When using a proper randomized padding scheme like PKCS1.5 type 2 padding or even better OAEP padding, there are no known attacks for even the smallest valid public exponent, 3. However, if for some reason the randomizer isn't working or perhaps random padding isn't used by mistake, an exponent of 3 make certain attacks possible where an exponent of 65537 does not. Using 65537 is not much slower than using 3 and does not provide a measure of protection for disastrous mistakes/bugs/failure.

Comment: This isn't about programming or development and is about cryptography; see for example https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48444/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80525/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66716/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22437/

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks! Did you mean to type "Using 65537 is not much slower than using 3 and DOES provide a measure of protection for disastrous mistakes/bugs/failure."?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, delete the word "not" from that sentence.